# Storing STL files in S3 bucket for rendering by STL Viewer javascript plugin in ASP.NET Core MVC View

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core (2.2) MVC website that uses the STL_Viewer javascript plugin.

One of the features is that I can display a rendered 3D model from an STL file in the browser. If I store the file locally to the website, this feature works fine.

Unfortunately, I'm running out of space with my webhost, so I want to use an S3 bucket to store the STL files.

I set up the bucket, at (fake name): https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com and set it to public. In the bucket I have a test file. We'll call it mystl.stl

I've tested the link in the address bar of the browser (multiple browsers) and it works. It downloads the file to my local downloads folder, so it doesn't seem like a permissions issue with the bucket.

But when I replace the local address ("/3dmodels/mystl.stl") with the s3 url ("https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mystl.stl") , it doesn't work. Nothing happens.

I added CORS to my project, using AllowMyOrigin and the s3 URL, and added the EnableCORS attribute to my Controller Action but still nothing.

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. After setting up the bucket, I needed to add info to the CORS tab (under permissions) to specify the allowed domain and what commands (GET) were allowed.